# How to change users smart quotes to dumb quotes in search bar?

Tags: search

I have a problem where smart quotes (curly) will not return any search results but dumb quotes (straight) will give what I expect.

I would like to give all users the same experience so I need to allow smart or dumb quotes to be entered in the search bar but would ultimately return the product with the dumb quotes as it is currently in the DB

I need to do this for both double and singles quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's a function that will filter the search query and replace any smart quotes with their "dumb" equivalent.

```php
<?php

/**
 * Filter smart quotes out of a search query.
 * Replace them with "dumb" quotes.
 *
 * @param WP_Query $query Instance of WP_Query.
 */
function filter_search_smart_quotes( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search() ) {
        $search = $query->get( 's' );

        $smart_quotes = array(
            chr( 145 ),
            chr( 146 ),
            chr( 147 ),
            chr( 148 ),
            chr( 151 ),
        );

        $dumb_quotes = array(
            "'",
            "'",
            '"',
            '"',
            '-',
        );

        $search = str_replace( $smart_quotes, $dumb_quotes, $search );

        $query->set( 's', $search );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_search_smart_quotes' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. unfortunately it did not work. the php chr( ) funtion can only look up to 255. the  unicode smart quotes are in the 8216 range. would this cause an issue.

Comment: As a test I added a simple letter  char ( 72 )  the uppercase H and swaped it to a B. but this also didn't work. so maybe there is a different wp function that can intercept it. They are woocommerce products, if this helps